# Xubuntu 22.04 keeps crashing after multiple fresh installs

Tags: xubuntu, crash, 22.04, dbus

I installed Xubuntu 22.04 about 6 times over the past couple days, but keep getting crashes. Crashes happen when watching/skipping videos on Youtube and also when playing games on Yuzu so I think it may be something to do with graphics.

I've been using Xubuntu for the past 2/3 years without problems, but can't get a stable install with 22.04. I tried:

- UEFI & BIOS installs
- Minimal installation & full installation
- Install with and without third party software
- With and without secure boot & CSM enabled in BIOS

All installs result in the same problems: Firefox/Youtube and Yuzu crashing the system and requiring a hard reset.

In syslog I see apparmor denying various Yuzu requests:

```
Jun  2 16:31:07 xubuntu kernel: [ 4499.190763] audit: type=1400 audit(1654183867.504:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.yuzu.yuzu" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/busnum" pid=4664 comm="libusb_event" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Jun  2 16:31:07 xubuntu kernel: [ 4499.302424] audit: type=1400 audit(1654183867.616:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.yuzu.yuzu" name="/run/udev/data/c234:2" pid=4664 comm="yuzu:input:SDL" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Jun  2 16:31:07 xubuntu kernel: [ 4499.307196] audit: type=1400 audit(1654183867.620:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.yuzu.yuzu" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/busnum" pid=4664 comm="libusb_event" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Jun  2 16:31:15 xubuntu dbus-daemon[1117]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/request/1_68/t" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop" pid=4664 label="snap.yuzu.yuzu" peer_pid=1667 peer_label="unconfined"
```

My PC crashed at 16:39 and I did a hard reset, but I can't see anything in the log at this time which explains the crash:

```
Jun  2 16:39:04 xubuntu kernel: [ 4975.891428] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049030] NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 2
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049033] Modules linked in: hid_sony ff_memless intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common amdgpu snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep iommu_v2 edac_mce_amd gpu_sched snd_pcm drm_ttm_helper ttm snd_seq_midi kvm_amd drm_kms_helper snd_seq_midi_event kvm snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel cec crypto_simd cryptd snd_seq rapl rc_core eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device fb_sys_fops k10temp snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt snd ccp soundcore joydev input_leds mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid mfd_aaeon asus_wmi nvme sparse_keymap platform_profile crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 nvme_core r8169 realtek ahci xhci_pci libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_amdpt video gpio_generic
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049072] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G      D           5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049075] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B350M-A, BIOS 5603 07/28/2020
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049077] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath.part.0+0x4f/0x200
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049084] Code: 0f ba 2b 08 0f 92 c2 8b 03 0f b6 d2 c1 e2 08 30 e4 09 d0 a9 00 01 ff ff 0f 85 22 01 00 00 85 c0 74 0e 8b 03 84 c0 74 08 f3 90 <8b> 03 84 c0 75 f8 b8 01 00 00 00 66 89 03 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049087] RSP: 0018:ffffafeac029ce30 EFLAGS: 00000002
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049089] RAX: 0000000000000101 RBX: ffffa03489df3dbc RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049090] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffa03489df3dbc
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049091] RBP: ffffafeac029ce58 R08: ffffa03489df3180 R09: 7fffffffffffffff
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049093] R10: 00000485ca592000 R11: 00000000000007b6 R12: 0000000000000002
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049094] R13: ffffa03790aa30c0 R14: ffffa03489df3dbc R15: 0000000000000003
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049095] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa03790a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049097] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049098] CR2: 00007fd3d48fa0b8 CR3: 0000000173056000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049100] Call Trace:
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049101]  <IRQ>
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049103]  native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x28/0x30
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049106]  _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x39/0x50
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049109]  try_to_wake_up+0x4f/0x5a0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049111]  ? update_process_times+0xc0/0xd0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049113]  ? tick_nohz_handler+0xb0/0xb0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049115]  ? __hrtimer_init+0x110/0x110
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049117]  wake_up_process+0x15/0x20
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049118]  hrtimer_wakeup+0x22/0x30
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049120]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x109/0x210
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049121]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x101/0x220
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049123]  __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x61/0xd0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049126]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x77/0x90
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049128]  </IRQ>
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049128]  <TASK>
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049128]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x12/0x20
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049130] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xd9/0x620
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049133] Code: 3d f4 4b 1e 56 e8 07 ae 6c ff 49 89 c7 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 58 ba 6c ff 80 7d d0 00 0f 85 5d 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 69 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 e3 03 00 00
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049134] RSP: 0018:ffffafeac0147e28 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049135] RAX: ffffa03790ab0f00 RBX: ffffa034831d4400 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049136] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049136] RBP: ffffafeac0147e78 R08: 00000485c5e59789 R09: 00000000000c3500
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049137] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 071c71c71c71c71c R12: ffffffffab4e60a0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049138] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 00000485c5e59789
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049140]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x620
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049142]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049143]  cpuidle_idle_call+0x13e/0x1e0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049145]  do_idle+0x83/0xf0
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049146]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049147]  start_secondary+0x12a/0x180
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049149]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4985.049152]  </TASK>
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4988.899378] show_signal: 20 callbacks suppressed
Jun  2 16:39:17 xubuntu kernel: [ 4988.899384] traps: xfwm4[1380] trap invalid opcode ip:7f1507851683 sp:7ffdde0758c0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.1[7f15077f9000+8f000]
Jun  2 16:39:18 xubuntu systemd[1]: Started crash report submission.
Jun  2 16:39:18 xubuntu whoopsie[5010]: [16:39:18] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Jun  2 16:39:18 xubuntu systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun  2 16:39:19 xubuntu systemd[1]: Started crash report submission.
Jun  2 16:39:19 xubuntu whoopsie[5013]: [16:39:19] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Jun  2 16:39:19 xubuntu systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Jun  2 16:40:31 xubuntu systemd-modules-load[335]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun  2 16:40:31 xubuntu systemd-modules-load[335]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
```

I can see an errors in /var/log/apport.log:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 4663) Wed Jun  1 19:48:24 2022: called for pid 1415, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 4663) Wed Jun  1 19:48:24 2022: executable: /usr/bin/thunar (command line "Thunar --daemon")
ERROR: apport (pid 4663) Wed Jun  1 19:48:25 2022: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
ERROR: apport (pid 4663) Wed Jun  1 19:48:25 2022: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 4663) Wed Jun  1 19:48:25 2022: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_thunar.1000.crash
```

I can watch YT videos or play Yuzu for a while without a crash, but at some point a crash happens on every session, requiring a hard reset.

I'm using a Ryzen 5 2400G CPU, I've had no problems with earlier Xubuntu versions. Anyone have any idea what's wrong or how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Assuming you're using the iGPU (which you didn't mention) the problems are likely one of the following: 1. Kernel version (try another kernel) 2. Firmware (try an older linux-firmware version) 3. BIOS problem (upgrade your Bios, but be careful, check your cpu is still supported in the latest bios provided by the manufacturer, sometimes they remove support for some models to make room for new ones)

Comment: I upgraded to kernel 5.18 and had a crash within 5 minutes. My BIOS is the latest version. I think I'll go back to 20.04, this isn't worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling [NO_HZ](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) fixed similar crashes for me.

Add `nohz=off` to kernel parameters:

- `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Add `nohz=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, e.g.:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` -> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nohz=off"`
- `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks but no help unfortunately. After I added the entries and rebooted, Yuzu crashed after less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @Johnny5ive Hmm, maybe I just got lucky. Just in case, can you share the log of the new crash? You did run `update-grub`, right?

Comment: Yeah I updated the grub. There isn't a log per se that pertains to the crash. I've been checking the kern.log sys.log and Xorg.log after the crashes but I can't see anything obvious in them. I did a fresh install again now, I decided to try Zorin, but unfortunately Yuzu still crashes and I had a crash when transferring files to a USB drive. I have been able to play Yuzu through Lutris without crashes so that's possibly 1 problem down but I'm getting crashes elsewhere too. I'm going ot try Zorin for a little longer and maybe try Linux Mint next. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but blacklisting the realtek r8169 module that drives the mobo nic of an AsRock A320M-HDV r4.0 significantly improved things here. Seems that like in the past realtek has several variants of the chip that play nice or not.